# code delivery in stream impact on another stream

Tags: rtc

If code is delivered to a stream will it have any impact on another stream which has the same component.

eg : 
stream 1 
Comp 1 - baseline 1

Stream 2
Comp 1- baseline 1

If a create a repo workpace out of stream 2 and make code changes and deliver to Stream 2  will the change be available in stream 1.

Are the components same or two different copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the components same or two different copies?

They are the same component.

But each stream only display the LATEST changesets delivered for that component.

That means delivering new change sets on Stream2 (and making a new baseline) has no effect on the same component on Stream1.

Comment: If the baseline is same in both the streams will the code delivery be impacted?

Comment: @user3302323 no both streams can start from the same baseline. That doesn't change the fact that each deliver to one stream will be independent and won't impact the other stream.

Comment: thanks for the answer because i need a trunk stream and a branch stream. So the content will be different in each stream . Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user3302323 it will be different if you start from different baselines (for the same component on two stream). If you start from the same baseline on each stream, the content will be the same. But even in that last case, you will still be able to deliver independent change set to their respective stream, means the content of the component will differ between each stream.

Comment: My scenario is i have a trunk stream to start . I create a baseline now for a component as basline 1 in stream1. I create branch stream 2 using baseline 1 of component. I now create a new repo space for stream 2 and checkin new changes, in this case are the contents different.

Comment: @user3302323 Exactly. Once you start delivered change set to stream 2, the content of the component will different from Stream 1, where said component remains unchanged.